# Windows Peer-to-peer Network

Tags: windows, networking, share

Our network is Windows-based p2p. All the computers use Windows 7.
I have the folder c:\Share\NWXTRN2 on my PC.
We have the PC with name XTRN2 and user name XTRN2 in the same Workgroup as my PC.
I need to share c:\Share\NWXTRN2 so that the only XTRN2 will have access to this folder in Windows Explorer.
Is it possible? Windows wizard offers me just Everyone in Share Permissions window.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible select share and add user to that share

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the users that are on my PC (named by Office-6):
Office-6\Administrator
OFFICE-6\Guest
etc. - all begin with OFFICE-6\, or Everyone. Others are impossible to add.